# How to restrict clients to not resell our API services?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-identity

I have an API to sell to some clients.
But I don't like to let clients to provide my API from their server to others.
What's the best way to apply such limitation?
I'm user ASP.NET with IIS.

Comment: Use authentication mechanism to make it secure

Comment: Of course it's secure but i don't need to give resell right to authorized clients to sell the APIs from their end.

Comment: The clients can make new API to call my API.then the can easily sell my API!

Comment: you have to add Key Mechanism, like SecreatKey, API Key, etc

Comment: You can only rely on behavior analysis to tell if the usage indicates the API has been resold or not, but that's not quite reliable either. IMHO, sell your API at a price that you can accept some level of misusage, as you cannot prevent such completely.